How to set VM Machine time using VM Virtual Box
How can the time be change for a vitual Machine using VM Virtual Box  (7.0.18)?
I've tried using the two commands as instructed here (Using virtual box is it possible to set your virtual machine time to be different from host time), but without success.
It was an old post, so perhaps the commands are different for a Windows10 OS?
Or perhaps their are other settings which override these commands.
Unfortunatly, their is no error message that I can see, just the time within the VM remains unaltered.
Thanks you in advance.
